# Viewing .txt encoding in powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding, header

I'm trying to list the encoding of a load of text files in a single folder and output it to a separate text file in powershell, I'm using the following function to identify the encoding by examining the headers of each file :-

```
    function Get-FileEncoding
{
    [CmdletBinding()] Param (
     [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True)] [string]$Path
    )

    [byte[]]$byte = get-content -Encoding byte -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4 -Path $Path

    if ( $byte[0] -eq 0xef -and $byte[1] -eq 0xbb -and $byte[2] -eq 0xbf )
    { Write-Output 'UTF8' }
    elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[1] -eq 0xff)
    { Write-Output 'Unicode' }
    elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0 -and $byte[1] -eq 0 -and $byte[2] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[3] -eq 0xff)
    { Write-Output 'UTF32' }
    elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0x2b -and $byte[1] -eq 0x2f -and $byte[2] -eq 0x76)
    { Write-Output 'UTF7'}
    else
    { Write-Output 'ASCII' }
```

I'm then using it in the following snippet to run it against all .txt files in the location:

```
Get-ChildItem  *.txt | select FullName, @{n='Encoding';e={Get-FileEncoding $_.FullName}}
```

The only problem is this is returning ASCII for every file, even those known to be Unicode/UTF8. Am I doing something really dumb here like only running it against the files name and not its actual contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
  if ( $byte[0] -eq 0xef -and $byte[1] -eq 0xbb -and $byte[2] -eq 0xbf )
  { Write-Output 'UTF8' }

  # FE FF  (UTF-16 Big-Endian)
  elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[1] -eq 0xff)
  { Write-Output 'Unicode UTF-16 Big-Endian' }

  # FF FE  (UTF-16 Little-Endian)
  elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0xff -and $byte[1] -eq 0xfe)
  { Write-Output 'Unicode UTF-16 Little-Endian' }

  # 00 00 FE FF (UTF32 Big-Endian)
  elseif ($byte[0] -eq 0 -and $byte[1] -eq 0 -and $byte[2] -eq 0xfe -and $byte[3] -eq 0xff)
  { Write-Output 'UTF32 Big-Endian' }
```

There is a detailed version of the function available [here.](https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2406504)